# Historical Instances like the settlement of Pitcairn Island

Tags: colonization, settlement

Are there any more instances in recorded history where a group of people have formed a isolated island society like the [mutineers of the HMS Bounty and their Tahitian captives did on Pitcairn Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitcairn_Islands#European_settlement)?

Comment: This is pretty much how Polynesians settled all the islands in the Pacific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article linked to in the question, the mutineers on Pitcairn were isolated from outside contact for less than 20 years (1790-1808).

There have been countless small [societies isolated from outside contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontacted_peoples) for centuries at a time. A notable example are the [Sentinelese](http://www.survivalinternational.org/campaigns/mostisolated) in the Andaman islands, who may have been isolated for as long as 60,000 years.

As for island [castaways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castaway), the Pitcairn islanders might be a unique case. However here's an interesting detail from a Wikipedia article about [Saint Helena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Saint_Helena):

> Sometime before 1557, two slaves from Mozambique, one from Java, and two women, escaped from a ship and remained hidden on the island for many years, long enough for their numbers to rise to twenty.

It's quite possible that other [maroon societies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maroon_(people)) were isolated for decades or longer, but I can't name any well documented case.

Comment: There was a case of a maroon community in Suriname(Guyana?) that was isolated long enough to form its own language out of the escapees' various languages. It was used as an example for a theory of language formation I heard about.